# Change layout depending on date format

Tags: android, layout, locale, date-format

I'm writing my own DatePicker dialog on Android. Depending on the locale, this dialog should show DMY, MDY or YMD format ([Wikipedia - Date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)). For example:

[image: MDY format]
[image: DMY format]

I can create a layout for every locale, but it would involve creating dozens of layouts. Is there a way to group locales to use the same resource?

Probably, the easiest solution is to detect the date format from the current locale (How can I get the order of the different elements?) and then swap the NumberPickers somehow.